# Unable to call OAUTH2 protected REST API using springboot3 and webclient

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-webclient

I am trying to write a simple application to invoke a REST API , which is OAUTH protected,  using springboot3 and webclient but server fails to start and gives this exception.

> required a bean of type
> 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrationRepository'
> that could not be found.

Here is my code -

```
@Configuration
public class WebClientConfig {

    @Bean
    public OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager(ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
            OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository) {

        OAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider = OAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder().clientCredentials().build();

        DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager = new DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientRepository);
        authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);

        return authorizedClientManager;
    }

    @Bean
    WebClient webClient(OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager) {

        ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction filter = new ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authorizedClientManager);
        filter.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("test-client");
        return WebClient.builder().apply(filter.oauth2Configuration()).build();
    }
}

@Component
public class WebClient {
    private static final String RESOURCE_URI = "https://localhost:8080/locations";

    @Autowired
    private WebClient webClient;

    public void logResourceServiceResponse() {
        String bodyValue = "hello world";
        Mono<String> result = webClient.post()
                .uri(RESOURCE_URI)
                .bodyValue(bodyValue)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class);
    }
}
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          test-client:
            client-id: test-clientid
            client-secret: test-secret
            authorization-grant-type: client_credentials
        provider:
          test-client:
            token-uri: https://localhost:9000/token
```

pom.xml

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <relativePath/> 
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>oauthclient</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>oauthclient</name>
    <description>Oauth2 client code</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Tried many samples from web but getting same error on startup with most of them. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: One working sample: https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_ui